# MPVolumeView route list not rotating with background window.rootviewcontroller

Tags: uiwindow, mpvolumeview

I am facing one problem with mpvolume View.
- it appears on screen as action sheet (i am sure it comes with uiwindow) once it appears
and if i change my device rotation my actualwindow.rootviewcontroller (which present the mpvolume view) not rotating.
along with that ui action sheet.

you can see example of it in whats app and goolge hangout.
in whats app screen is able to rotate, but in hangout it is not rotating with device orientation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1 Take Viewcontroller class in use mpvolumeview from it,
step 2 than put the view controller as a root view controller and make window as key window.

main window respond to orientation and new window for mpvolume view will also respond.

it is working for me ...